# Problems with including files for ASP in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic

thanks for taking the time to read this question of mine, which I'm sure is a school boy error but for the life of me, cannot see it.

I have an ASP page which has the following contents:

```
<!-- #include file="include.asp" -->
<%
Dim ConfigFile
ConfigFile = Left(Request.ServerVariables("URL"), InStr(Request.ServerVariables("URL"),"/framework/lib/dms/asp/"))
ConfigFile = ConfigFile & "project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp"

%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%=ConfigFile%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Which works when accessed as a stand-alone page, or when called via an iFrame (don't ask). However, if I add the line "include ConfigFile" the page returns a 404 error in IIS. The value of ConfigFile is "/cms/project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp", as printed out in the body of the page.

If I add the line "include https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cms/project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp" to replace the original include statement, it works as intended.

Now I'm sure that this is a configuration error, but either though I put the ASP setting "enableParentPaths" to true and scrip "errorsenttobrowser" to true, I'm still not getting anywhere.

I have identical code on another server running an older version of IIS and it is working fine, however, I never setup the original server and have no documentation for setting up the new server.

The ASP script which causes the 404 error looks like:

```
<!-- #include file="include.asp" -->
<%
Dim ConfigFile
ConfigFile = Left(Request.ServerVariables("URL"), InStr(Request.ServerVariables("URL"),"/framework/lib/dms/asp/"))
ConfigFile = ConfigFile & "project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp"

include ConfigFile
%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%=ConfigFile%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But this file works fine:

```
<!-- #include file="include.asp" -->
<%
Dim ConfigFile
ConfigFile = Left(Request.ServerVariables("URL"), InStr(Request.ServerVariables("URL"),"/framework/lib/dms/asp/"))
ConfigFile = ConfigFile & "project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp"

include "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cms/project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp"
%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%=ConfigFile%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Regards

Comment: what exactly have you written in the include statement? <!--#include file="/cms/project/config/ConfigDms.inc.asp"-->? the slash at the beginning means iis looks at the root of the web.

Comment: The include file on line 1 works fine, that isn't an issue. The second include file which isn't listed in the code above, but mentioned in the text below, simply contains a number of CONSTANT for defining set variables. Adding the contents of this file to the code above works as well, so it isn't the file content that is the problem (since it also works when I use the full https:// path to the file). The path to the file is taken from the root of the website.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning for getting 404 errors when trying to access a particular page, was indeed correct. A colleague of mine changed the default error messages for bespoke ones, but failed to copy the actual HTML error pages onto the server.

This meant a 500 error was detected, tried to display the 500.html page but couldn't find it and hence displayed a 404 error.....

Sorry for anyone who has spent time reading this...